# How can I reset the password on a Windows 7 VM under VMware 4 on Mac Lion?

Tags: windows-7, security, vmware, osx-lion, passwords

I have a Mac running Lion, and a Windows 7 virtual machine running under VMware 4. The problem is that the password was lost in a phone upgrade.

Is there any way using command line or other tools on the host to reset the password?

Comment: Do you mean your Windows account/login password, or a password to the encrypted virtual machine?

Answer (score 4):

Grab the NTPassword reset ISO from [here](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) and mount it inside your VM. Reboot the VM and boot to the ISO, follow the instructions for resetting the Administrator account (just blank it as opposed to creating a new one), and reboot. You can now log in with the Administrator account (no password) and change it the usual way through the Control Panel.

Comment: Seems like this option no longer works (or at least not for VMs). Tried on Windows 7 VM @ VMWare Player 10. Says something about not being able to find NT hash, so passwords cannot be reset.